# cannot install npm in MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, node.js, npm

My laptop cannot run the command 'npm' now.

I work in a group for my coursework using Node.js plus Express.
first time, I installed the node.js and express in my laptop. One of group member put application package on the Git and I just need to connect with the Git and not necessary to install Node and Express individually. So I tried to connect with Git with commands; $git pull, and install package with $ npm install, it works well.

Then, I deleted Node.js and Express files in my local driver in the laptop, and connect with Git using the same codes above, whilst $npm doesn't work as well. The error always is 'command not find'.  help!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Git and NPM are unrelated however you may be using them both for your project. Git is a version control system and NPM is a Package Manager for Node.js

Reinstall Node.js (NPM comes with it too by default) from http://nodejs.org/